# Failing to get mysqli query to insert values into mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to mysql queries and just couldn't get this mysqli statement to insert into mysql. Is there something wrong with my script setup or my $sql? (I am getting no errors though, its just not inserting)

```
    <?php

$login = "coolkidz";  //this line insets into username
$sname = "heyu";
$city = "beautiful";
$empass = "awesome";
$eusername = "what";
$mcode = "nice";


$sql = "INSERT INTO login(sname, city, empass, eusername, mcode, username) VALUES('$sname', '$city', '$empass', '$eusername', '$mcode', '$login')");

    $hostname_Database = "censored";
    $database_Database = "censored";
    $username_Database = "censored";
    $password_Database = "censored";

    $mysqli = new mysqli($hostname_Database, $username_Database, $password_Database, $database_Database); 
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
       printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
       exit();
    }

    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    if (!$result) {
       printf("%s\n", $mysqli->error);
       exit();
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Mention the error you are getting

Comment: That's the thing. I'm not getting any errors. It's just not inserting for some reason

Comment: change `mysqli_connect_error()` to `$mysqli->connect_error` also change `mysqli_connect_errno()` to `$mysqli->connect_errno`

Comment: @Ravi That is assuming he's running PHP 5.2.9 or 5.3+ (`$mysqli->connect_error` isn't available before those versions).

Comment: that extra `)` in query `$sql=` may also result in an error, check that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Please update "..'$var'..." to  "..'" . $var . "'..." like ex:
=>
$sql = "INSERT INTO login(sname, city, empass, eusername, mcode, username) 
     VALUES('" . $sname . "', '" . $city . "', '" . $empass . "', '"
     . $eusername . "','" . $mcode . "', '" . $login . "')";
```

Comment: Because it is used in double quotes, that isn't needed

Answer (score 0):

You have this line:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO login(sname, city, empass, eusername, mcode, username) VALUES('$sname', '$city', '$empass', '$eusername', '$mcode', '$login')");
```

Try and change that to something like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO login(`sname`, `city`, `empass`, `eusername`, `mcode`, `username`) VALUES('$sname', '$city', '$empass', '$eusername', '$mcode', '$login')";
```

Note the ` at the columnames,

and you had one `)` to much at the end of the line

Comment: @user1803649, i don't understand. didn't my answer worked? : => bacause string is not found value and throw error.

Comment: @vikramjain, so you're saying that the string aren't inserted in the sql string? And what about this then?:[phpnet](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)

Comment: Thanks for contributing TWCrap, but I couldn't get yours to work. Thanks though!